# How to deal with Carpenter Bees boring into my front porch?

Tags: wood, pest-control

I noticed a single "bumblebee" hovering in front of my front door for days.  When my handyman was out doing some repairs, he told me that it isn't a bumblebee, but a carpenter bee.  Then he showed me where carpenter bees had bored a hole into the wood above my porch.

I called a couple of pest control companies.  They said that sealing the hole now is risky because if I seal the hole and don't get every bee and egg inside, I run the risk of them boring new holes to get out.  They recommended sealing the hole in the fall.

I like bees, but I draw the line at letting them eat my house.

- What recommendations do you have for dealing with the carpenter bees?
- When do the lady bees lay their eggs? Based on the time of year, should I wait until the fall to seal the hole?
- Is Diatomaceous Earth effective against them? Should I put some in the hole?
- Are traps effective?

Comment: I spent many a summer patrolling my backyard to keep carpenter bees off our wooden split rail fence. A badminton racket dispatches them quite easily, since they're prone to hover in the same spot. I eventually graduated to shooting them out of the air with a BB gun too. Although now I think I'd opt for a non-lethal solution like Fiasco Labs'.

Answer (score 1):

Spar varnish, no exposed natural wood.

Stain doesn't cut it, they hate gnawing through paint.

We use a couple red or incense cedar chunks in various places like you use Zinc sacrificial anodes for marine electrolysis control.

Answer (score 1):

These flying drill-bits are common in my area. Having a professional exterminator treat the fascia boards with insecticide every few years is effective and doesn't do huge amounts of harm to the environment.

(I do know folks who have the exterminator on contract, covering this plus barrier spraying for ants plus anything else that comes up. I haven't felt the need yet; the first treatment seems to have lasted five years so far.)

BTW, only female bees can sting. The males will threaten but can't harm you. If a carpenter bee has a white spot on its head, it's a male; swat it at will.